Ubuntu 22.04 takes over a minute to wake from deep suspend
After looking at the dmesg, I can see that it looks like the cause of the delay is the PCIEport 0000:20:00:0 which is not ready.
running lspci -s 20:00.0 shows:
20:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Maple Ridge 4C 2020] (rev 02)

Result of dmesg:
[   27.942301] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[   33.905213] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[   34.946828] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: broken device, retraining non-functional downstream link at 2.5GT/s
[   35.954833] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: retraining failed
[   37.206830] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: broken device, retraining non-functional downstream link at 2.5GT/s
[   38.214812] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: retraining failed
[   38.214829] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 1023ms after resume; waiting
[   39.254820] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 2047ms after resume; waiting
[   41.334816] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 4095ms after resume; waiting
[   45.686816] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 8191ms after resume; waiting
[   54.134821] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 16383ms after resume; waiting
[   70.774829] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 32767ms after resume; waiting
[  105.590814] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: not ready 65535ms after resume; giving up
[  105.591021] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591264] pcieport 0000:21:02.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591287] pcieport 0000:21:01.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591331] pcieport 0000:21:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591358] pcieport 0000:21:03.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591442] thunderbolt 0000:22:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.591522] xhci_hcd 0000:56:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  105.654524] ACPI: EC: event unblocked

This is a Thinkpad X1 Extreme gen 5 with kernel 6.5.0-1020-oem.
I am stumped what to do next. Anyone have any ideas?

I added the kernel parameter:
pcie_aspm=off
This seems to solve the problem, although it might be ideal?

I have the same device and the same issue.
Appending pcie_aspm=off in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT property of the /etc/default/grub file solved the problem for me.

I also had this problem. first stage :
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

second stage :
Replace this line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

Save and then the third step:
sudo update-grub

Then restart the system once

What does the nouveau.modeset=0 option do?
